# Java Style with-respect-to Multiple Returns, Used as "Guards"

Tags: java, coding-style

is there a school of thought in the Java community with-repect-to using multiple returns in a method, in the manner shown below:

```
public SomeClass someMethod(int someValue) {
    if (someValue < SOME_CONSTANT) {
        return null;
    }

    SomeClass someClass = null;
    // and now, the body of the method that performs
    //   the heavy lifting
    return someClass;
}
```

I "grew up" under the mantra "single-entry-point, single-exit-point", but I can see how using simple guards could make code more readable/maintainable (i.e., eliminate levels of nesting). The "single-exit-point" version would look like...

```
public SomeClass someMethod(int someValue) {
    SomeClass someClass = null;

    if (someValue < SOME_CONSTANT) {
        // and now, the body of the method that performs
        //   the heavy lifting
    }
    return someClass;
}
```

This is, admittedly, somewhat of a trivial example, but I can see where more preconditions could result in greater nesting. Personally, I still would hold to "don't sprinkle returns throughout the method" for other purposes (i.e., only "return" as the result of a guard, or at the end of the method), but I'm wondering how the rest of the Java community feels.

added "apple example"...

```
public Pie makeApplePie(Apple apple) {
    if (apple == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // do cool stuff with apple
    return new Pie();
}
```

Comment: `someMethod` in the example you've described appears to perform *two* roles, as opposed to one. Typically, I would do `someValidation` in a method, and if it passes, then `someMethod` otherwise keep working until `someValidation` passes. If you have a method `cutApple` that accepts Objects that are not Apple, but does nothing with non-apples, why not just verify the Object is an Apple before asking to cut it?

Comment: You've somewhat missed the point of my question. If I wanted to have "apples", then I'd type the parameter (vice doing a separate validation). But, using your example. I added an "apple example" to my original question. But my original question regarding using returns as guards the a method's main implementation remains.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/coding-style/info

Comment: I've absolutely never understood the single exit rule. As far as I'm concerned, it's the exact opposite of good style. Early exits are good, delayed exits are poor. It's a rule that people follow for its own sake. There is no value in having a single return statement. As in your example, contorting yourself to have one return leads to creating unnecessary return value variables. Honestly, I have never found myself confused wondering where a function returns from. It's just not a point of confusion that needs to be mitigated.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely prefer single exit unless your logic forced you to. Sometimes there may be a for loop inside of which you computed your result and thus want to break.
And then there may be more statements after for loop which you don't want to execute but right away return then you have no choice but to have multiple `return` statements

Below code :

```
public  SomeClass myMethod()
{
   SomeClass sc = null;

   for ( int i = 0; i < (someCondition); i++ )
   {
      //computed result
      sc = result;
      return sc; //result is SomeClass
   }

   //Some more machinery to assign a value to sc

   return sc;
}
```